# Código não está sendo lido por completo

Tags: php, mysql

Em meu arquivo Controller, apenas o 'return View' está sendo lido, o código seguinte, passa-se direto e finaliza.

```
public function naocadastrado()
{
    return View('/naocadastrado');


    $user = new \App\User();
    $user->Name = Input::get('Name');
    $user->User = Input::get('User');
    $user->Password = hash('sha256', Input::get('Password'));
    $user->Tipo = Input::get('tipo_usuario');


        if("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM tabela WHERE campo='User'"){

            return redirect('/cadastroexistente');

        }else{

            return redirect('/cadastrado');
        }

    $user->save();

}
```

---

```
public function naocadastrado()
    {
        return View('/naocadastrado');
    }

    public function ncadastrado()
    {
        $user = new \App\User();
        $user->Name = Input::get('Name');
        $user->User = Input::get('User');
        $user->Password = hash('sha256', Input::get('Password'));
        $user->Tipo = Input::get('tipo_usuario');


            if("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM tabela WHERE campo='User'"){

                return redirect('/cadastroexistente');

            }else{

                return redirect('/cadastrado');
            }

        $user->save();

    }
```

Eu dividi:

WEB.PHP

```
Route::group (['prefix' => '', 'namespace' => 'Api'], function(){

Route::get('/naocadastrado', 'CadastroController@naocadastrado');

Route::post('/naocadastrado', 'CadastroController@ncadastrado');
});
```

BLADE

```
<body>


    <form method="POST" action="/ncadastrado">

        <h1> Cadastro de Usuários UNIUS <br> </h1>
        <h2> USUÁRIO NÃO CADASTRADO<br> CADASTRE-SE! </h2>

        <label><b>Nome:</label> <input type="text" name="Name"> <br>
        <label><b>E-mail:</label> <input type="text" name="User"> <br> 
        <label>Senha:</label> <input type="password" name="Password" > <br>
        <label>Tipo de usuário</label>
        <select name="tipo_usuario">
                <option value="">Selecione</option>
                <option value="Administrador">Administrador</option>
                <option value="Desenvolvedor">Desenvolvedor</option>
        </select><br><br>              
        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" id="cadastrar" name="cadastrar">

    </form>





</body>
```

Comment: vc está verificando um string com algo no if logo sempre é true.Tem coisa faltando.

Comment: não irá continuar nada mesmo, logo na primeira linha do metodo já tem o return, depois disso vc pode colocar o que quiser que nunca será executado.

Comment: Entendi! Obrigada xD

Comment: Por que desse return logo na primeira linha? Como o MarceloDiniz o código restante não será executado. E na parte do IF, faça o comando para executar a query antes e depois compare para ver se retornou algum registo, tipo rowCount ou verificando se é true para executar o bloco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem um `return` na primeira linha da função `naocadastrado`:

```
return View('/naocadastrado');
```

Todo o código a seguir a essa linha não será executado. Veja o que diz a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.return.php) do PHP:

> A declaração return retorna o controle do programa para o módulo que o chamou. A execução continuará na expressão seguinte à invocação do módulo.
>
> Se chamada dentro de uma função, a declaração return terminará imediatamente sua execução, e retornará seus argumentos como valor à chamada da função.

Ou seja:

```
function a() {
    echo "Executou a função 'a'";
    b();
}

function b() {
    echo "A função 'a' executou a função 'b'";

    return;

    c();
}

function c() {
    echo "A função 'b' executou a função 'c'";
}

a();
```

Teriamos a seguinte saída:

> - Executou a função 'a'
> - A função 'a' executou a função 'b'

Repare que na função `b` há um `return` antes da chamada a função `c`, logo a função `c` não será executada, pois a função `b` retornou o controle para a função `a`.

Comment: Ainda não está indo! Vc pode ver meu código abaixo?